# Прекращение выполнение процедуры

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

В общем, есть процедура c `SET XACT_ABORT ON` и вложенные процедуры с `SET XACT_ABORT ON` при некоторых проблемах я вызываю `RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,15,1)` в надежде прекратить выполнение кода, но тем не менее выполнение продолжается...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А вызов или текст процедуры обернут в транзакцию?

Comment: Нет. Но разве SET XACT_Abort не должен на первой же ошибке вызывать падение? И к тому же у меня там обычные селекты на проверку условий.

Comment: попробуйте `return` - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, т.е нельзя как в ком-нибудь языке программирования кинуть ошибку, что без перехвата она была причиной падения? return я вернусь из внутренней процедуры, а как внешняя поймет, что ей тоже не нужно продолжать работу из-за проблем во внутренней?

Comment: если верить докам, то `Инструкция THROW учитывает SET XACT_ABORT. Инструкция RAISERROR — нет. В новых приложениях следует использовать инструкцию THROW вместо RAISERROR.`

Comment: но вы можете с помощью `return` возвращать какое-то число и по нему определять - продолжать процедуру или прерывать и текущую

Comment: Здесь (раздел Causes the statement batch to be ended?) описано поведение (англ.): http://sqlhints.com/2013/06/30/differences-between-raiserror-and-throw-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 4):

> Что я делаю не так?

Вы пытаетесь осуществлять управление *порядком выполнения*, опираясь на особенности `XACT_ABORT`, но опция `XACT_ABORT` в большей степени предназначается для управления *транзакцией*.

Инструкция `RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,15,1)` не вызовет прерывания выполнения, если не находится в блоке `TRY ... CATCH`, даже при включенном `XACT_ABORT` (`THROW` вызвал бы, но в SqlServer 2008 этой инструкции ещё нет). Для прерывания выполнения лучше всё-же полагаться на соответствующие *control flow* инструкции - `RAISERROR` (с соответствующим уровнем *severity*) в блоке `TRY ... CATCH`, либо `RETURN`.

Т.е., если, например, изначально имеется

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OuterProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC InnerProc;
    PRINT 'Continue execution';
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE InnerProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF 1 = 1
        RAISERROR('Error', 15, 1);

    PRINT 'Something else';
END;
GO
```

Достаточно будет использовать блок `TRY ... CATCH` во внешней процедуре

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OuterProc
AS
BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC InnerProc;
    PRINT 'Continue execution';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @msg nvarchar(4000), @severity int, @state int;
    SET @msg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    SET @severity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    SET @state = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR(@msg, @severity, @state);
END CATCH;
GO
```

Если внутренняя процедура может вызываться независимо, то может потребоваться её тело также обернуть в `TRY ... CATCH`, или добавить `RETURN` следом за `RAISERROR`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InnerProc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Error', 15, 1);
        RETURN;
    END;

    PRINT 'Something else';
END;
GO
```